# How to get a program/instrument title from a specific chunk of a MIDI file in DryWetMidi library?

Tags: c#, midi

I'm using DryWetMidi library in C# and trying to acquire a program/instrument title from a loaded chunk, but I fail to find such field that gives me the title.
So far I just have:

```
var midiFile = MidiFile.Read("test.mid");
var tempoMap = midiFile.GetTempoMap();
var trackList = midiFile.GetTrackChunks().ToList();
var notes = trackList[0].GetNotes().ToList();
```

I expected to find something like:

```
var programNumber = trackList[0].ProgramNumber;
```

or

```
var programNumber = midiFile.GetProgramNumbers();
```

But I can't find such operations.
Please let me know if there's any way to do this in DryWetMidi or in any external library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TrackChunk](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/api/Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Core.TrackChunk.html) has [Events](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/api/Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Core.TrackChunk.html#Melanchall_DryWetMidi_Core_TrackChunk_Events) property which gives access to all MIDI events within a track chunk. Just find [ProgramChangeEvent](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/api/Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Core.ProgramChangeEvent.html) ones and collect program numbers:

```
var programNumbers = trackList[0]
    .Events
    .OfType<ProgramChangeEvent>()
    .Select(e => e.ProgramNumber)
    .ToArray();
```

DryWetMIDI has complete documentation. Please look into it to learn more: https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi.